# How to exceed the limit of scan data for 1mb in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am using dynamodb with nodejs, I am having 3000 records, and I am writing 60+ segments in the code, each segment scanning the data of 1mb and displaying the results to 60+ segments of 1 mb limit. So please provide the solution how to get the 3000 records scan in single step that means in one segment. Please provide the solution quickly because i am strucked in the middle of my project. Please help me. Below is my code.

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var async = require("async");

    AWS.config.update({
      region: "---",
      endpoint: "-----------",
      accessKeyId: "-----------------",
      secretAccessKey:"----------"
    });


var db = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()

var table = "rets_property_all";
var pstart =new Date () .getTime ();

async.parallel({
            0 : function(callback){
        db.scan ({TableName: table,
          ProjectionExpression: "#cityname,ListingKey ",
          FilterExpression: "#cityname = :v_id",
          ExpressionAttributeNames: {
              "#cityname": "CityName",
          },
          ExpressionAttributeValues: {":v_id" : 'BALTIMORE'},
            TotalSegments: 63,
            Segment:  0//by the worker who has been called
        },function (err , res) {
            callback (null , res.Items);
        });
            },
            1 : function(callback){
        db.scan ({TableName: table,
          ProjectionExpression: "#cityname,ListingKey ",
          FilterExpression: "#cityname = :v_id",
          ExpressionAttributeNames: {
              "#cityname": "CityName",
          },
          ExpressionAttributeValues: {":v_id" : 'BALTIMORE'},
            TotalSegments: 63,
            Segment: 1//by the worker who has been called
        }, function (err , res) {
            callback (null , res.Items);
        });
            },
      2 : function(callback){
        db.scan ({TableName: table,
          ProjectionExpression: "#cityname,ListingKey ",
          FilterExpression: "#cityname = :v_id",
          ExpressionAttributeNames: {
              "#cityname": "CityName",
          },
          ExpressionAttributeValues: {":v_id" : 'BALTIMORE'},
            TotalSegments: 63,
            Segment: 2//by the worker who has been called
        }, function (err , res) {
            callback (null , res.Items);
        });
            },
--------
---------
------

      62 : function(callback){
        db.scan ({TableName: table,
          ProjectionExpression: "#cityname,ListingKey ",
          FilterExpression: "#cityname = :v_id",
          ExpressionAttributeNames: {
              "#cityname": "CityName",
          },
          ExpressionAttributeValues: {":v_id" : 'BALTIMORE'},
            TotalSegments: 63,
            Segment: 62//by the worker who has been called
        }, function (err , res) {
            callback (null , res.Items);
        });
      },

        },function(err,results){
      if (err) {throw err; }
      var pend = new Date () .getTime ();

      console.log (results);
        })
```

Answer (score 9):

Actually, there is no way to override the **1 MB limit** of scan. This is the DynamoDB design restriction and can't be overridden by any API. You may need to understand the limitation of the architecture or AWS service design.

You can use `LastEvaluatedKey` on the subsequent scans to start from where the previous scan ended.

> The result set from a Scan is limited to 1 MB per call. You can use
>   the LastEvaluatedKey from the scan response to retrieve more results.

The use case is unclear why you wanted to get all 3000 records in one scan. Even, if you have a specific use case, simply it can't be achieved on DynamoDB scan.

Even, in relation database, you get the cursor and go through the iterations to get all the records sequentially. Similarly, in DynamoDB you have to use Scan recursively until `LastEvaluatedKey` is null.

**Sample code for single scan recursively until LastEvaluatedKey is null:-**

```
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
var params = {
    TableName: table,
    ProjectionExpression: "#cityname,ListingKey ",
    FilterExpression: "#cityname = :v_id",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#cityname": "CityName",
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":v_id": 'BALTIMORE' }
};

docClient.scan(params, onScan);

function onScan(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to scan the table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        // print all the movies
        console.log("Scan succeeded.");
        data.Items.forEach(function (movie) {
            console.log("Item :", JSON.stringify(movie));
        });

        // continue scanning if we have more movies
        if (typeof data.LastEvaluatedKey != "undefined") {
            console.log("Scanning for more...");
            params.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey;
            docClient.scan(params, onScan);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want all 3000 records in one scan due to performance issue. It is taking 4.5 sec. For improvement of this is there any solution.

Comment: Please provide proper code if there is any correction in the above code.

Comment: @purushottam same problem here, I am doing 15 seconds for just 130 records. (requires 4 fetches of 1MB). It's kind of impossible to work with. I guess I have to redesign my table, and make my Items smaller. (which is really dissapointing).