# Typescript module augmentation with a third party module and namespace

Tags: typescript, amazon-dynamodb, module-augmentation

So, I wanted to extend the AWS SDK `DynamoDB` class to have a new `scan` implementation that overcomes the 1 MB limitations (see [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html) and [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43199385/how-to-exceed-the-limit-of-scan-data-for-1mb-in-dynamodb)). Found documentation on typescript module augmentation (looked at the example in the [official docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) and [relevant SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44196107/augmenting-an-interface-that-lives-in-a-declared-namespace-in-typescript)) and even though the SO example actually shows how to extend a third party class, my solution (designed in a similar way), does not work. So here is my extension:

```
import * as AWS  from "aws-sdk";

declare module "aws-sdk" {
    namespace AWS {
        interface DynamoDB {
            scanAll(params: any): any;
        }
    }
}

AWS.DynamoDB.prototype.scanAll = async function(params: AWS.DynamoDB.Types.ScanInput) {
    let items : any[]
    let db = <AWS.DynamoDB> this;
    var result = await db.scan(params).promise()
    if (result.Items)
        items.concat(result.Items);
    while (result.LastEvaluatedKey) {
        params.ExclusiveStartKey = result.LastEvaluatedKey;
        result = await db.scan(params).promise()
        if (result.Items) {
            items.concat(result.Items);
        }
    }
}

export {}
```

Typescript build gives an error on the line `AWS.DynamoDB.prototype.scanAll =`

```
TS2339: Property 'scanAll' does not exist on type 'DynamoDB'.
```

I would assume the namespace comes into play here? But how to solve this ?

I tried omitting the namespace like this:

```
import * as AWS  from "aws-sdk";

declare module "aws-sdk" {

        interface DynamoDB {
            scanAll(params: any): any;
        }

}

DynamoDB.prototype.scanAll = async function(params: AWS.DynamoDB.Types.ScanInput) {
    let items : any[]
    let db = <AWS.DynamoDB> this;
    var result = await db.scan(params).promise()
    if (result.Items)
        items.concat(result.Items);
    while (result.LastEvaluatedKey) {
        params.ExclusiveStartKey = result.LastEvaluatedKey;
        result = await db.scan(params).promise()
        if (result.Items) {
            items.concat(result.Items);
        }
    }
}

export {}
```

but then Typescript does not even find the type `DynamoDB` and gives me:

```
TS2304: Cannot find name 'DynamoDB'.
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50322026/925141) helped me with a similar issue I was having when trying to augment some AWS CDK classes. My first attempt was to do something like this:

```
 declare module "@aws-cdk/aws-kms" {
  interface Key {
    myStuff(): void;
  }
 }

Key.prototype.myStuff = function (): void {...}
```

But that doesn't work and I hit the same issues as you. What I really needed was this:

```
import { Key } from "@aws-cdk/aws-kms/lib/key";
 
declare module "@aws-cdk/aws-kms/lib/key" {
  interface Key {
    myStuff(): void;
  }
 }

Key.prototype.myStuff = function (): void {...}
```

The difference is that you need to use the full path to the modules type rather than just the module package name. Things get more complicated when the authors of a 3rd party module have the Typings split across multiple files. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53366179/typescript-module-augmentation-with-modules-in-multiple-files) covers some of those nuances.

In the end, I was able to get some signs of life in my solution and looking at the next hurdle. Hope this provides some insight into module augmentation.

Comment: I spent a good couple of hours fighting this before I came across your post. Works perfectly!

Comment: Glad it was helpful! It was a pain to get that sorted out initially, but now that I have a better understating about it all works, Typescript is really growing on me after the past 9 months.